# How to draw a thick merging arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need a tikz diagram like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to merge a thick arrow. This is what I have done so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle] (P0) at (0, 2) {$P_0$};
    \node[draw,circle] (P1) at (0, 0) {$P_1$};
    \node[draw,circle] (Pn) at (3.5, 1) {$P_n$};
    \node[draw,single arrow,inner sep=10pt,minimum height=2.3cm,rotate=-15] at (1.6,1.6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need open arrows or solid ones would be sufficient?

Comment: @DanielN I think this kind of arrow looks better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This might be a possibility.  The idea is in the question: use the merging point to create the special arrow.

- The arrows are created using two strokes: a black one first and a white smaller one second.
- For the special arrow, a second passage is needed to obtain the correct merging result (the style `detail` in the code).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  whole/.style={%
    line width=2ex,
    arrows={-Latex[length=2.2ex, width=5ex]},
    shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex,
    postaction={%
      draw, white, line width=1.77ex,
      arrows={-Latex[length=1.76ex, width=4.3ex]},
      shorten <=2.15ex, shorten >=2.3ex
    }
  },
  ipart/.style={
    line width=2ex, shorten <=2ex, shorten >=0ex,
    postaction={
      draw, white, line width=1.77ex,
      shorten <=2.15ex, shorten >=-.5pt
    }
  },
  fpart/.style={
    line width=2ex,
    arrows={-Latex[length=2.2ex, width=5ex]},
    shorten <=0ex, shorten >=2ex,
    postaction={
      draw, white, line width=1.77ex,
      arrows={-Latex[length=1.76ex, width=4.3ex]},
      shorten <=-.05ex, shorten >=2.3ex
    }
  },
  detail/.style={
    white, line width=1.77ex, shorten <=2.15ex, shorten >=0ex
  }
}
\tikzmath{
  real \dy;
  \dy = -.5;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, thick, circle, inner sep=1ex}]
  \path
  (0, 0) node (A) {A}
  (0, -2.2) node (B) {B}
  (4, 0) node (C) {C};
  \path ($(B)!.5!(C) + (0, \dy)$) coordinate (M);

  \draw[whole] (A) -- (C);

  \draw[ipart] (A) to[out=-60, in=180] (M);  
  \draw[ipart] (B) to[out=20, in=180] (M);
  \draw[detail] (A) to[out=-60, in=180] (M);
  \draw[fpart] (M) to[out=0, in=240] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```